# With JS Grab the inner text of a php echo result, put the text in a JS variable, and use that variable for a if statement JS

Tags: javascript

HTML code:

```
 <tr><td colspan=3><p id="mu"></p></td></tr>
```

PHP code :

```
 if($utilizator_check==0)
    {
        echo "valabil";
    }else if($utilizator_check==1) {
     echo "nu";
    }

JS code :

    function validateForm()
    {
        var uv=document.getElementById("mu");
        try
        { 
        var uvb = document.getElementById("mu").innerText;
        var bun = "valabil";
         if (uvb == bun ) {} throw "Nu este valabila";
        }
        catch(err)
        {
        uv.innerHTML="Eroare: " + err + ".";
        return false;
        }
    }

function checkusername(){
    var status = document.getElementById("mu");
    var u = document.getElementById("utilizator").value;
    if(u != ""){
        status.innerHTML = 'Se verifica...';
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST", "ceck.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
            }
        }
    var v = "name2check="+u;
    hr.send(v);
    }
}

HTML code

    <input id="sub" type="image" name="submit" value="submit" onclick ='validateForm();' src="poze/trimite.jpg" alt="Trimite" />
```

What i do wrong in js ? How can I put php text echo result from "mu" into JS variable?
**I can't use document.onload because php echo response will appear in real time when the user put text in username textbox, not when form or page load**  I need the variable of js to take the php echo result and work with result when user click the submit button

Comment: Are you adding an event handler when the document is loaded? `document.onload = function() { var uv = document.getElementById("mu"); /* ... */ };`. If not, you're trying to access a not-yet-created DOM object. By the way, when doing `uv.innerHTML = "";`, you are **deleting** the contents of the `uv` object (so `innerText` will be an empty string). You don't want that.

Comment: I can't use document.onload, I try to explain why above

Comment: Try this: `<form action="..." method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">`. When submitting the form, `validateForm()` will be called before. If it returns `false`, form won't be submitted.

Comment: I have this code : <form id="..." action="..." name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post"> and still does not work

Comment: What does the Javascript console say?

Comment: I don't think I have the console but when user write text in username textbox, php verify the user in database and in real time php give me the response in "mu", if is available he give me the result "valabil" and if not he give me the result "nu", and this text result i need js to take it and put it in a variable. I must say the php code is not in the html form where is the js script. Php code is in separat file. The response from php in "mu" it's working perfectly. Thanks, I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Now the error **"Nu este valabila"** it's appear when I press the submit button indifferently of php variable.